# How can we convert an integer to string in AngularJs

Tags: angularjs

How can we convert an `integer to string` in AngularJs, like `parseInt()` converts `string to int`.
I tried wit `$parse`, which itself is a wrong approach I think..

Comment: Integer to string is as simple as calling `.toString();`

Answer (score 73, accepted):

`.toString()` is available, or just add `""` to the end of the `int`

```
var x = 3,
    toString = x.toString(),
    toConcat = x + "";
```

Angular is simply JavaScript at the core.

Comment: This answer works. In case if we are reading the `x` as a variable, it is good to use 

`if ( x != null ) x = x.toString();`

Thanks

Comment: Yep, ionic 3+ with the .tostring() doesn't seen to work, but the + ""; works like a dream!

Answer (score 0):

```
var x : number = 3;
var st : string = String(x);
console.log(st);
```